# Writing and reading files

Tags: python

So I made a script like this:

```
a = open("movies.txt","r")
```

And I wanted to write something in this so I did:

```
a.write("EndGame")
```

But it said it could not write, why?

Comment: Because you opened the file for reading only.

Comment: You used the read handler, `"r"`. Instead, use `a = open("movies.txt","w")`. Check out [this link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: You're mixing up the [three Rs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_three_Rs).

Comment: Welcome to Stack OverFlow! Your question currently a [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates), which doesn't meet this site's requirements. Please edit your question following these guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because you have entered a wrong file mode. You used `r` which stands for reading while you should use the `w` for the writing. That code should work.

```
a = open("movies.txt","rw")
a.write("EndGame")
a.close()
```

Comment: There is one double quotation mark missing behind `"rw`. I just cannot add it myself because SO keeps telling me that edits must alter at lest 6 chars.

Comment: @DanielB. thank you, I just made a stupid typo :)

Comment: @DanielB. Thanks for the hint. I corrected the code.